# How to preserve session in a client server app

Tags: http, session, grails, client

I have a Grails web service running and I have to connect to it with the Android client app.
After the user log in, the user gets an userID. I need to call a function for streaming several messages from the grails web service, but for calling that function, before, it call another function which check the access of the user checking its userID. When i try to call it, the userID has disappeared, probably becouse i didn't keep any session.
I wonder if anyone knows how to solve it...

Comment: It might help us answer if you shared some code demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it creating a global private DefaultHttpClient and using it in the different functions.